# IC can light with holes

Tags: electrical

[image]I was sealing around air leaks in the attic and realized one can light had holes in it. My impression was that means the can was not IC compliant. I took the trim off and it does say IC on the sticker. Is it normal to have holes in these cans?

Comment: Yes. They dissipate heat.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's normal.

The holes do not go all the way through but to a space that is covered by another can that does not have holes and can be in contact with the insulation.

Just in case there is also a thermal safety switch within the fixture that automatically turns off the light when too much heat from the bulb has been trapped and the temperature to rise to a certain point. Once the fixture has cooled, the switch turns the light back on again.